# Do grpc services support primitive types?

Tags: grpc, protobuf-net, grpc-c#

I am trying to refactor some services with grpc json transcoding but have problems with understanding how to do some things. If anyone has some good documentation or tutorial it would be great.
Is it possible to make something like this

`rpc Search (string) returns (SearchResponse) {}`

or all parameters must be actually a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or all parameters must be actually a message?

Yes, basically

I have plans to simplify that in protobuf-net.Grpc (so that the machinery hides all that from you), but: that isn't the case today.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That seemed to me as a case but was not sure because just started with it.